# Is there a function like "corr" from python, in c++ for finding the pairwise correlation of columns? Whilst working with Armadillo/Mlpack?

Tags: python, c++, pandas, correlation

I need to get this code (Python)

```
corr = X.corr()
```

into C++, where X is a huge dataset with more than 10x10 in my case something like nearly 450x30. So there are a lot of columns to calculate the correlations.
I'm working with C++ and Armadillo/Mlpack.

I found another solution on stackoverflow where someone recommended using

```
arma::vec result = arma::conv(a, arma::reverse(a));
```

as this should be the same as xcorr in MATLAB which is essentially the same as this?
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html

But I need this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Would it be an option do run the "xcorr" solution in a loop for each #i & #i+1 column in the data?

Or is there a better way in using the same as ".corr" in C++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#cor

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you! I just compared them in python (X.corr()) and c++ (armadillo cor(X,X)) with a sample, and they show the same output. So that pretty much saved me from doing it myself, I looked the whole time for it, but it didn't occur me that it could be written with only one "r" as google didn't show me anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to work most with Armadillo from R so this is wrapped in an R context though the simple example function is plain C++.  As the documentation will tell you, 'matrix on matrix' also works returning respective pairwise correlations.  Here, for simplicity, it is just two columns.  Unsurprisingly, R gets the same number:

#### Code (with R glue and example)

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double mycorr(const arma::vec & x, const arma::vec & y) {
    return arma::as_scalar(arma::cor(x, y));
}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
cor(x,y)
mycorr(x,y)
*/
```

#### Output (from R)

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68749299/answer.cpp")

> set.seed(123)

> x <- rnorm(100)

> y <- rnorm(100)

> cor(x,y)
[1] -0.0495321

> mycorr(x,y)
[1] -0.0495321
>
```